# STL Algorithm element wise multiplication WITHOUT sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I would like to multiply two vectors (element-wise), save the result, and then take the sum. I know the function from stl algorithm

```
std::inner_product(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), 0);
```

This doesn't save the result of the product. Do you know if such a function exists without doing the sum of all resulting elements? I couldn't find this myself. I need this to be super-optimized for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean standard algorithm `std::transform`.

If you want to store products of corresponding elements of two vectors in some third vector then you can write like

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

//,,,

std::vector<int> v1 = { /*...*/ };
std::vector<int> v2 = { /*...*/ };
std::vector<int> v3;

v3.reserve( v1.size() );

std::transform( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
                std::back_inserter( v3 ),
                std::multiplies<>() );
```

Or a more complete example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> v3;

    v3.reserve( v1.size() );

    std::transform( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
                    std::back_inserter( v3 ),
                    std::multiplies<>() );

    for ( int x : v3 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 4 3
```

Or maybe it would be better to use type `long long int` for the products in the example above

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 3, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<long long int> v3;

    v3.reserve( v1.size() );

    std::transform( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
                    std::back_inserter( v3 ),
                    std::multiplies<long long int>() );

    for ( int x : v3 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Can't you see the duplicate?

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist See my updated post.

Comment: I saw that... what am I supposed to do? I can't delete the question when it's answered!

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist You should do nothing.:) My answer is good enough.:)